# wp_get_post_terms() returns WP_Error in functions.php but in template it works

Tags: functions, taxonomy

```
$my_post_id = 644;
$areas = wp_get_post_terms( $my_post_id, 'area-trabajo' );
var_dump($areas);
```

This code, in functions.php, returns:

```
object(WP_Error)#3178 (2) { ["errors"]=> array(1) { ["invalid_taxonomy"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(20) "Taxonomia no vÃ¡lida" } } ["error_data"]=> array(0) { } }
```

But in a template, returns the expected result:

```
array(1) { [0]=> object(WP_Term)#7194 (11) { ["term_id"]=> int(150) ["name"]=> string(13) "Restauración" ["slug"]=> string(12) "restauracion" ["term_group"]=> int(0) ["term_taxonomy_id"]=> int(150) ["taxonomy"]=> string(12) "area-trabajo" ["description"]=> string(0) "" ["parent"]=> int(0) ["count"]=> int(1) ["filter"]=> string(3) "raw" ["term_order"]=> string(1) "0" } }
```

What could be the reason that in the functions.php returns invalid_taxonomy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you dump the code into `functions.php`, then the custom taxonomy hasn't been registered, because it isn't recommend to register custom taxonomies earlier than the `init` hook.

Running the code within the template hierarchy files should work, because it's later than `init`.

If you want to run it within the `functions.php` file, make sure to hook it accordingly.

Comment: I se.. actually I have the code inside: `add_action('init', 'save_job_candidate_still');` , Could I use a different hook that is executed before the template? ( as i'm validating a $_post request in there )

Comment: You can also try a different priority, like `add_action('init', 'save_job_candidate_still', 999 );` Better yet check the code where you registered the custom taxonomy. @ToniMichelCaubet

Comment: hm... that's going to be complicated, because I defined using the toolset plugin ( used to be named wp custom fields.. ), i'll try with the 999. Thanks!

Comment: You can e.g. check the hook sequence  [here](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference) in the Codex. There are also plugins out there that should be able to show you this in detail @ToniMichelCaubet